# Filtering and extracting PIDs as space-separated list from ps using sed

Tags: text-processing, ps

I want to filter and format the output of `ps -ax -o pid,command`, but not sure what pipe to use for it.

I want to filter those lines matching a fixed string at a fixed position, just keep the pids for the matched lines, and output them as a space-separated list such as `1234 5678 33121`.

I can trivially do the first step using `| egrep 'regex'`, but the second step probably needs sed or something, and I can't work it out. Since sed (and awk) also handle regex filtering, I probably don't need grep.

Multiple space characters are fine, and sort order isn't important, so there's no need to trim the PIDs or order the lines. Example:

```
$ ps -ax -o pid,command

  PID COMMAND
    0 [kernel]
    1 /sbin/init --
...
  255 /usr/local/sbin/check_status
  268 /sbin/devd -q
 1435 (unlinkd) (unlinkd)
 1974 sleep 60
 7414 /bin/sh /var/db/test/update.sh
21848 ps -ax -o pid,command
39207 /usr/local/sbin/syslog-ng -p /var/run/syslog-ng.pid
```

find all processes whose command begins /usr/ (ie lines `matching /usr/ in chars 7-11` or the regex `^[0-9 ]{5}\s\/usr\/`) and return their pids (or `first 5 chars`) on a single line space-separated. Output:

```
255 39207   (no \n's, amount of spacing unimportant).
```

I've tried but sed isn't the easiest command to figure out.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to take all the digits of the pid you could use `pgrep` to do this for you:

```
pgrep -d " " -f ^/usr
```

will print a space separated list of all the PIDs of processes whose command starts with `/usr`

If you really want to use the `ps` command, `awk` would be a better tool than `sed` to do what you want.  You could do it, with just the first 5 characters of the PID like:

```
ps -ax -o pid,command | awk '$2 ~ /^\/usr/ {printf( "%s ", substr($1,0,5));} END {print ""}'
```

This will check if the second field starts with `/usr` and if so print up to the first 5 characters of the first field followed by a space, then I threw in a newline at the end for good measure, but you could remove that if you don't want a newline even at the very end

As Giles pointed out, you'll probably never really want just the first 5 characters of a PID (that was probably me misreading the question) so the more useful answer using `awk` would be:

```
ps -ax -o pid,command | awk '$2 ~ /^\/usr/ {printf( "%d ", $1);} END {print ""}'
```

Comment: Eric, you just have beaten me by 5 seconds :)

Comment: pgrep was what I needed - and the awk version will be insanely useful if I hit a variant that pgrep/pkill can't solve... which I just did: "kill all processes that match this regex *and* have a pid in this list". I might be able to solve it now, though, but any hints appreciated :)

Comment: @Stilez if you're not opposed to a second grep, just pgrep regex | egrep pid1|pid2...

Comment: Make that `{printf "%d ", $1}` to simply print the PID plus a space.

Comment: @giles agreed to get the whole PID it's in `$1`, but I had been thinking the OP was asking for just the first 5 chars of the PID (which is probably not really very useful) when they said " their pids (or first 5 chars)".  So I was offering that as a way to get the first 5 chars, but I'll include your suggestion as it's probably more useful in general